# How to bind Knockout viewModel for only available keys?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am creating knockout `data-bind` properties dynamically using .cshtml in MVC. I want to bind only those properties which are available in viewModel which again I am creating dynamically from the result of restful WCF.

So there may be or may be not some keys available in the viewModel for which 
e.g.: `<span data-bind="text: cli"></span>` is created.

But when I bind the viewModel, I get an error along the lines of "'cli' property not found in viewModel". However, I wanted to bind that property only if that key is there in viewModel in the first place.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: requestURL,
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data.GetCircuitCheckStatusResponse.Status.HasErrors == false) {
                        networkData = data.GetCircuitCheckStatusResponse.Response.RunningStatus.networkData;
                        diagnosticData = data.GetCircuitCheckStatusResponse.Response.RunningStatus.diagnosticData;
                        diagnosticsInfo = {};
                        //To Create boxPanel Datas
                        for (var i = 0; i < networkData.length; i++) {
                            diagnosticsInfo[networkData[i].ItemTitle] = networkData[i].itemValue;
                        }
                        //To Bind the data using Knockout 
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            debugger;
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(diagnosticsInfo);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            // Every time data is received from the server:
            //ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);

        });
```

```html
@foreach (var nameValue in childContainer.NameValueImageItemsList)
                                {
                                    var cssClass = "nameValueItem floatLeft" + " " + nameValue.DataBindName;
                                    <div class="@cssClass" style="">@nameValue.DisplayName</div>
                                    <div class="@cssClass" style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" ><span data-bind="text: CLI"></span></div>
                                    <div class="@cssClass" style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;">
                                        <a>
                                            @if (nameValue.IconImageURL != null && nameValue.IconImageURL != "")
                                            {
                                                <img src="@nameValue.IconImageURL" alt="i"/>   
                                            }
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearBOTH"></div>
                                }
```

Comment: Only possible way I think of is you should do `<!-- ko if:cli -->//your html element <!--/ko-->`

Comment: Can you please clarify the whole approach..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it worked for me:

```html
 <span data-bind="text: $data['@nameValue.DataBindName'] "></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really straightforward way to do this:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  description: 'some description'
  // ,title: 'my title'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Description: <span data-bind="text: description"></span><br />
Title: <span data-bind="text: !!title ? title : ''"></span>
```

A related option may be that you create a `safeTitle` computed property on your view model:

```js
var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.description = 'my description';
  //self.title = 'my title';
  self.safeTitle = ko.computed(function() {
    return !!self.title ? self.title : '';
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Description: <span data-bind="text: description"></span><br />
Title: <span data-bind="text: safeTitle"></span>
```

Furthermore, you could also do it with a function, so you don't have to create an observable for each property:

```js
var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.description = 'my description';
  //self.title = 'my title';
  self.safeGet = function(prop) {
    return !!self[prop] ? self[prop] : '';
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Description: <span data-bind="text: description"></span><br />
Title: <span data-bind="text: safeGet('title')"></span>
```

Note that this code would be slightly different if those properties are observables, and even more different (and complicated) if it can be either.

Yet another option may be to check out point 3 of [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html), on wrapping existing bindings: you could create another "text" binding that guards against this situation.

PS. I'd carefully rethink your design. Most likely the fact that properties are "optional" is related to some domain concept.

PPS. You could also consider using the Null Object Pattern server side, and this problem goes away entirely.

PPPS. Here's one final way to circumvent the problem, (logical, but) much to my surprise:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  desc: 'some description'
  // ,title: 'my title'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Description: <span data-bind="text: $data.desc"></span><br />
Title: <span data-bind="text: $data.title"></span>
```

Comment: I tried doing the way u suggested still getting an error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'cli' is undefined". I believe this is happening as even the key is not created in the knockoutViewModel and we are checking if it is not null... There is going to be properties which will be undefined...Not getting how to handle this... I am new to Knockout..Please suggest!!

Comment: I'm sorry mate, but your comment makes absolutely zero sense to me. Try to edit and improve your question so it reproduces your actual scenario, and we can provide more specific help.

Comment: just one thing  how to handle if "cli" or any other property is not in the viewmodel...like <span data-bind="text: cli==undefined ?cli:''"></span>

Comment: That comment also makes very little sense to me. You should really update your question, improve it, add any details (and pay extra attention to proper spelling, grammar, interpunction, markdown, and overall readability).